# Getting /bin/sh: adb: command not found issue when running app on android in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting `/bin/sh: adb: command not found` issue when running app on android using react native. The app icon displays but app is not opening here is attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing and setting up the environment variable for the same?

You can install it from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb?gclid=Cj0KCQjwwb3rBRDrARIsALR3XeYc8OAGciPpnCBHfwZY6uj6HA0ty5It9AJ2W-OKnXYpee-VUeLwyRMaAqEaEALw_wcB

Comment: I have created local.properties file to set sdk directory @NehaSaggam

Comment: So for adb (path) to be resolved in the command prompt you need to set environment variable the way you do it, for example, for JAVA

Do you have /platform-tools in SDK directory?

Comment: how to set envirment variable in mac ? @NehaSaggam

Comment: Add it to you .bashrc / .zshrc file

Comment: Can you please send a screenshot i am new to mac @NehaSaggam

Comment: `cd ~` , now check if you have .bashrc or .bash_profile or .zshrc file using cmd `ls -la`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198937/discussion-between-neha-saggam-and-s-hashmi).

Answer (score 1):

Install adb, from [here](http://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html)

For more info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb?gclid=Cj0KCQjwwb3rBRDrARIsALR3XeYc8OAGciPpnCBHfwZY6uj6HA0ty5It9AJ2W-OKnXYpee-VUeLwyRMaAqEaEALw_wcB)

Then set PATH environment variable in .bashrc / .bash_profile / .zshrc(whichever you have).

On a new terminal try command `adb`. It should be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal that you put "npx react-native run-android", set environment variables again like:

- `source $HOME/.zprofile` (if you use zsh)
- `source $HOME/.bash_profile` (if you use bash)